# decl_runtime_api behaving in a weird way

Tags: pallet, runtime, api

In the [project](https://github.com/revoltez/validated-streams/) we are currently working on, we declared some [runtime apis](https://github.com/revoltez/validated-streams/blob/51d5a3ebbd5ee5177c11792562fb8ba986a8f2b8/pallet/src/lib.rs#L196-L214) in our custom pallet, we tried to update the dependencies from `0.9.28` to `0.9.42` but the build fails with the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `R: pallet::Config` is not satisfied
   --> pallet/src/lib.rs:196:2
    |
196 | /     sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
197 | |         /// Get extrinsic ids from a vector of extrinsics
198 | |         /// that should be used to quickly retrieve all the event ids (hashes) given a vector of
199 | |         /// extrinsics currently used to inspect the proposed block event ids and whether they are
...   |
210 | |         }
211 | |     }
    | |_____^ the trait `pallet::Config` is not implemented for `R`
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro `sp_api::decl_runtime_apis` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting type parameter `R`
    |
211 |     }, R: pallet::Config
    |      +++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

this error is a bit misleading as far as I understand since I'm already implementing `pallet::Config`, so I decided to run a minimal setup with substrate-node-template and see if there are any problems with the macro itself.

In the latest version in substrate-node-template, I tried adding the following runtime api in the template pallet:

```
sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
    pub trait ExtrinsicDetails<R> where R:crate::Config
    {
        fn dummy_test(runtime: R::length) -> R;
    }
}
```

given that I declare length in the pallet::Config like this:

```
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
    type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
    /// Type representing the weight of this pallet
    type WeightInfo: WeightInfo;
    #[pallet::constant]
    type length: Get<u32>;
}
```

and implemented like this:

```
impl pallet_template::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_template::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type length = ConstU32<100>;
}
```

it kept throwing this error:

```
 error[E0220]: associated type `length` not found for `R`
     --> /home/coder/project/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:114:30
      |
  114 |             fn dummy_test(runtime: R::length) -> R;
      |                                       ^^^^^^ there is a similarly named associated type `length` in the trait `pallet::Config`
```

even though it has the same name, i also tried using `pallet::Config` instead of `crate::Config` and also just `Config`, all have the same error.

Ps: same code was working in 0.9.28

Comment: Can you share the repo?

Comment: @Bruno question updated!

Answer (score 0):

Error resolves for me on `v0.9.40` by capitalizing the letter `L` in these two places:

pallets/template/src/lib.rs

```rust
type Length: Get<u32>;
```

runtime/src/lib.rs

```rust
type Length = ConstU32<100>;
```

Comment: still does not work, using latest rust latest update in both stable and nightly, didn't work, and sometimes when i use R directly for example in a trait methid parameter `dummy_test(my_type: MyType<R>)` and my MyType is defined in the module like this `type MyType<T> =BoundedVec<u8, T::Length>` it show this error: `associated type `Length` not found`

Comment: Best to push up your code so I can pull and test it.

Comment: Alright, here is the repository that im working with currently `https://github.com/revoltez/validated-streams`, its not minimal setup but nothing too complicated, its very similar to what i asked but this time it always gives this error: `^ the trait `pallet::Config` is not implemented for `R` `, i'll update the question to this repository if needed

Comment: even though its implemented and it also suggests to to further restrict it by retyping the same bound `}, R: pallet::Config`

Comment: question updated!

Comment: fixed it with 0.9.40, i'll leave this question open since the problem is in 0.9.42